# im trying to find the largest files created or modified within the last 10 days within Linux

Tags: linux, bash

im trying to find the largest files created or modified within the last 10 days within Linux.

I wanted to find all files which exceed 100MB in size but were created in the last 10 days.

Almost along the lines of the below

find / -type f -size +100000k -exec ls -lShr {} ; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }' | sort -k 5 -r -h

-mtime -10 -ls

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-printf` of GNU `find`:

```
find / -size +100M -mtime -10 -printf '%s\t%p\n' | sort -n
```

Comment: thank you for this,is there a way to covert the bytes to either MB or alternate data format?

Comment: @bhirst You may try `find / -size +100M -mtime -10 -printf '%s\t%p\n' | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)[0-9]\{6\}/\1/' | sort -n`. This will round down the size to MBs.